# How to find date of specific day in specific week

Tags: php, date

I have Googled and searched on here for the answer. I'm either searching for the wrong thing or what I'm asking can't be done (which I hope it can)

I need to find the **date** of a **specific day** in a **specific week**. For example, I want to know what Tuesday's date was in week 34, or Friday's date in week 2 was.

My PHP skills are introductory and I've tried to piece together and manipulate using what I already have, but nothing has worked.

Comment: please include your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use compound formats

```
echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '2015W342' )); // 2015-08-18
```

where the values are:

> **2015**-Year
>
> **W34**- Week no
>
> **2**- Day of the week

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use strtotime like

```
print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next Monday',strtotime('2016-01-01 +34 week')));
print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Monday',strtotime('2016-01-01 +34 week')));

#check if one of the dates is correct
var_export(date('W',strtotime('2016-10-10'))==34);
```

see documentation an that topic